# sphinx.so not loaded in ubuntu 8.04

Tags: php5, ubuntu-8.04, sphinxsearch

I've installed the sphinx extensions via pecl on ubuntu 8.04

however, after restarting apache, my php program says that SphinxClient hasn't been found
I looked at phpinfo() output and its not there.

I've looked at where extension_dir is set to and the sphinx.so is there

any idea why it won't load?

php version is PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer

turns that instead of adding:
extension=sphinx.so

under "Dynamic Extension" in the php.ini,

you need to create a file in /etc/php5/cgi/conf.di
called sphinx.ini
with the line

extension=sphinx.so

now works